# Batch convert state plane coordinates to lat long with multiple SPC Zones?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates, convert, state-plane

I'm somewhat of a GIS novice and am trying to see if this is possible to save me some time with further investigating. I have about 300 records in a CSV file with the fields SPC Zone, ECOORD, NCOORD, CRDUNITS, and a point identifier.

I was wondering if there is any possible way to batch convert these points (all with differing SPC Zones) to lat long in QGIS or some other application?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a partial solution, and I think there might be a bug, but here goes.

Given a CSV that looks like this:

[image]

You can load the CSV into QGIS and use the DB Manager Query window to perform SQLite / sql spatial functions on your data.

```
select 
c.*
, make_point(c.x, c.y) as geom 
from libraries_denver_csv as c
```

This basically turns the two coordinate values into a geometry object that can be drawn on the map:

[image]

Now what I *thought* would be possible would be to simply apply the ST_Transform / Transform function on that constructed geometry and use the value in the spc_zone column to serve as the SRID integer for that transformation.

However, I keep getting a NULL response, and can't figure out why - perhaps this doesn't exactly work in SQLite - and if anyone can add some info, I would appreciate it (as this question came up this morning on a local GIS forum as well):

```
select 
c.*
, make_point(c.x, c.y) as geom 
--test with value from spc_zone column
, Transform((make_point(c.x, c.y)), cast(spc_zone as integer)) as geom_transform
--test with single known SRID value to apply for all records
, Transform((make_point(c.x, c.y)), 3857) as geom_transform

from libraries_denver_csv as c
```

But unfortunately this consistently yields a NULL response:

[image]

Does anyone know why that might be happening?

Comment: The x and y columns are longitude and latitude. spc_zone has what is probably EPSG:3857, AKA 'web mercator' or 'WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator'. Try using 4269 (NAD83) or 4326 (WGS84) instead.

Comment: @mkennedy Hi Melita - I think this might be a bug with the DB Manager transform functions - this works on an existing geometry (from a SHP, for example), but not when trying the Transform(geom, srid) function on the geometry built from makepoint(x,y) in DB Manager....

Comment: Ah, I see. Can you figure out what coordinates are in the geom?

Comment: @mkennedy in my example above I'm using WGS84/4326. The 'geom' column is the result of the makepoint(x,y) function.